# Data from Two View Controllers added to Third View Controller

Tags: swift

I want to send information from textfields on VC one to confirmationVC. Similarly, I then want to send information from textfields on VC two to confirmationVC. ConfirmationVC should display the data entered in VC one and VC two but the app crashes.

NOTE: VC one and VC two are on the same VC file (RegisterVC). VC three is in its own VC file (ConfirmationVC). Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYxwm.png) of the three view controllers.

I get the following error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

Thanks for any help!

```
//Source VC
class RegisterVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
var firstNameS = ""

@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
var lastNameS = ""

@IBOutlet weak var birthday: UITextField!
var birthdayS = ""

@IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!
var heightS = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func sendPage1(_ sender: Any) {
    self.firstNameS = firstName.text ?? "empty"
    self.lastNameS = lastName.text ?? "empty"
    self.birthdayS = birthday.text ?? "empty"


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "P1", sender: self)
}



@IBAction func sendPage2(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.heightS = height.text ?? "empty"

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "P2", sender: self)
}




override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var vc = segue.destination as! ConfirmationVC // connect both VC's

    vc.confirmFirstNameD = self.firstNameS
    vc.confirmLastNameD = self.lastNameS
    vc.confirmBirthdayD = self.birthdayS
    vc.confirmHeightD = self.heightS

}

}


//Destination VC
class ConfirmationVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var confirmFirstName: UILabel!
var confirmFirstNameD = ""

@IBOutlet weak var confirmLastName: UILabel!
var confirmLastNameD = ""

@IBOutlet weak var confirmBirthday: UILabel!
var confirmBirthdayD = ""

@IBOutlet weak var confirmHeight: UILabel!
var confirmHeightD = ""




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    confirmFirstName.text = confirmFirstNameD
    confirmLastName.text = confirmLastNameD
    confirmBirthday.text = confirmBirthdayD
    confirmHeight.text = confirmHeightD
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @BCza stated, it is best if you split your code into two separate view controllers, as they collect different data, after all. You can pass the information from the first VC to the second, and then all of the info from the second to the ConfirmationVC. Your code would be like this:

**First VC**

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
var firstNameS = ""

@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
var lastNameS = ""

@IBOutlet weak var birthday: UITextField!
var birthdayS = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func sendPage1(_ sender: Any) {
    self.firstNameS = firstName.text ?? "empty"
    self.lastNameS = lastName.text ?? "empty"
    self.birthdayS = birthday.text ?? "empty"

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "P1", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var vc = segue.destination as! SecondVC // cast to SecondVC to set the saved values below

    vc.savedFirstName = self.firstNameS
    vc.savedLastName = self.lastNameS
    vc.savedBirthday = self.birthdayS    
}

}
```

**Second VC**

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!
var heightS = ""

//These will be given a value upon segueing from the first view controller to the second
var savedFirstName = ""
var savedLastName = ""
var savedBirthday = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}   

@IBAction func sendPage2(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.heightS = height.text ?? "empty"

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "P2", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var vc = segue.destination as! ConfirmationVC // pass the data from both VC's to ConfirmationVC

    vc.confirmFirstNameD = self.savedFirstName
    vc.confirmLastNameD = self.savedLastName
    vc.confirmBirthdayD = self.savedBirthday
    vc.confirmHeightD = self.heightS

}

}
```

Comment: This worked for me! It's literally like bulldozing all the variables to the end. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first VC isn't connected to your Confirmation VC. The Segue is pointing to your second VC which isn't that type. So when you say,

`var vc = segue.destination as! ConfirmationVC`

the app will crash.  You need to have different segues since you *do* want to go to have different destinations for each one.

Also, I would highly recommend having different classes for your VC's. It will make your code a lot easier to work with and debug.